# Transact Sql Query with double quotes and field names containing spaces?

Tags: t-sql, xaf, xpo

I have the following code that produces sql with field names delimited by quotes

```
using DevExpress.Data.Filtering
```

with

```
CriteriaOperator criteria = StockFilter.GetCriteria();  
string sWhere = CriteriaToWhereClauseHelper.GetMsSqlWhere(criteria);
```

This produces SQL like the following which runs ok in SQL Server Express 2017

```
select * from  myextitem           
where  (isnuLL(CharIndEX(N'te', myextitem."Description"), 0) > 0)
```

However I want to use the [Item Number] field instead of the Description field.

When I try

```
select * from  myextitem           
where  (isnuLL(CharIndEX(N'test', myextitem."[Item Number]"), 0) > 0)
```

I get a message

```
Invalid column name '[Item Number]'.
```

I have thought of parsing the text to replace "[Item Number]" with [Item Number]
which would produce this sql that works

```
select * from  myextitem           
where  (isnuLL(CharIndEX(N'text', myextitem.[Item Number]), 0) > 0)
```

but am hoping there is a more general way.

I am mindful that this code is vulnerable to SQL Injection depending on the source of the test text.

Comment: Presumably this SQL is being constructed using both types of delimiters - you would use `[ ]` *or* `" "`. There's probably a configuration option somewhere to control the quote delimiters. It's only added square brackets to the column name containing a space, so if you didn't have problem characters like spaces in your column names this would probably not be an issue. Stick with underscore or camel case, it just makes life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CriteriaToWhereClauseHelper.GetMsSqlWhere(criteria)` method has an overload which allow you to prevent the quotes.

```
string sWhere = CriteriaToWhereClauseHelper.GetMsSqlWhere(criteria, setQuotedIdentifiersOff: true);
```

There's another method signature which allows you to pass in your own property formatter function (`Func<OperandProperty, string>`).

```
string sWhere = CriteriaToWhereClauseHelper.GetMsSqlWhere(criteria, (operandProperty) => operandProperty.PropertyName)
```